# Open multiple .obj files in meshlab from command line?

Tags: 3d, mesh, meshlab

Using meshlab I am able to open an `.obj` file with the command `meshlab example.obj`

I would like to open multiple files at once bu I can not seem to figure it out. I have tried `meshlab example1.obj example2.obj` and `meshlab exaxmple*` without any luck...

Is this possible from the command line, or is there a good way to do this?

Comment: do you able to open OBJ file on the computer screen?

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use meshlabserver, which is the command line version of meshlab. To load multiple `.obj` files, the command would be: `meshlabserver -i example1.obj -i example2.obj -i example3.obj`, etc.
I hope that helps!